# If $M$ is a closed connected $R$-orientable $n$-manifold then a fundamental class for $M$ exists

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, Theorem 3.26(a) is:

**Theorem 3.26.**(a) Let $M$ be a closed connected $n$-manfold. If $M$ is $R$-orientable, the map $H_n(M;R) \to H_n(M,M-x;R)\cong R$ is an (group) isomorphism for all $x \in M$.

Here $R$ is a ring with identity.

A **fundamental class** for $M$ is an element of $H_n(M;R)$ whose image in $H_n(M,M-x;R)\cong R$ is a generator(unit) for all $x \in M$.

Hatcher comments that, by (a), a fundamental class exists if $M$ is a closed connected $R$-orientable $n$-manifold. But I can't see how this hold because the map $H_n(M;R) \to H_n(M,M-x;R)\cong R$ is a group homomorphism, not a ring homomorphism. How can I show this?

This result would be obviously true when the following holds, but I even can't see that this is true.

For a ring $R$ with identity, if $f:R \to R$ is a (additive) group isomorphism then it is a ring isomorphism, or more generally, sends $1_R$ to $1_R$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maps $H_n(M;R) \to H_n(M,M-x;R)\cong R$ are not just isomorphisms of groups but of $R$-modules.  In particular, they map generators as an $R$-module to generators as an $R$-module (which, in the $R$-module $R$, are the units).